# Segmentation fault after installation

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I know there are a log of questions with this subject, however I can't find an answer for my problem.
I have a program that I build on a linux-VM without any problems. I can run the program. 
I have created an installation file for this program. In this installation-structucture I can find my build program. On this location everything runs without a problem.

If I install my program on another linux-VM I get the error "Segmantation fault (core dumped)". This error occurs also when I run my program from the temporary folder where my original project is copied to for installation. It contains the same files as on the first VM in the installation structure.

The only answer I found so far is a problem with pointer pointing to the wrong peace of memory. But I can't believe this is it, because my program runs fine on the first VM. Can anybody help me where I should start looking?

Comment: You should start with some prints along your program in order to locate the line where it's failing. Or even better if you know how to do it: use some debug tool like the one provided with netbeans to follow the execution of your program line by line.

Comment: Or better yet, compile a debug build and run in a debugger.

Comment: I inherit the program. It contains 5 solutions an over 2000 files. First I have to be able to build an distribute it before I get the time to start digging in the code. So adding some prints isn't so easy.

Comment: I made a debug build an ran it in debugger. This didn't give any problems.

Comment: Are the permissions set on this new machine? Try to run your application under root account, if you didn´t do it already.

Comment: Did you examine the core file with gdb?

Comment: So, the release build segfaults but debug build doesn't? Try compiling  with exactly the same arguments as when you get segfault but add the `-g`

Comment: Something appearing to "run fine" being equated to being well-defined is a mistake. *Observed* behavior should not be equated to *defined* behavior. You cannot assume the latter is true because the former is so. There are many reasons a program can crash, almost-all of them involve invoking a violation of the latter. You need to debug that core file, at the dry least the call-stacks for where things went south. And walk your code path you at-least *think* is tripping up via visual inspection.

Comment: Running a debug build with valgrind often helped me to find segfaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to debug it or use strace:

`strace ./nameOfYourBinary`

(sudo apt-get install strace if you have not it)

this should help in finding what is going wrong with your program.
Maybe the VM where the program fails have not enough memory (or whatever) to run your program.
Check also all your malloc, if you have them in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I used strace in the VM that failed and compared it to the strace in the VM that works fine. Now I know there's a problem with the license files.